# Why does deleting the transform property of a rotated object change the object's location?

Tags: inkscape, transform, rotate

Why does the location of an object change when I delete it's transform property?

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create a rectangle and select it.
2. Click again to get to see the rotation handles and rotate it a bit.
3. Use XML editor (Shift-Ctrl-x) to edit the rectangle's properties and delete the 'transform' property.

After step 5 the rectangle changes location, and not to the initial position of the rectangle. I've not seen a pattern to what controls the new location.

The location also changes if I instead of deleting the property change e.g. 'rotate(15)' to 'rotate(0)'.

I wonder what is going on here?

Background: I had read this question [Reset rotation point to center of object](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/132488/reset-rotation-point-to-center-of-object) and was just trying things.

PS.
Inkscape 0.92 on Ubuntu.

Comment: I think there was just such a question on here asked a couple days ago... Found it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60185907/svg-coordinates-why-x-y-change-when-transform-rotate